# Eliminate selectively members from an array in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

There should be a way to do it in Wolfram Mathematica ...
I want to eliminate from an array the members that have a corresponding Null on another one.
E.g. if I have

```
X = {8.26953, 11.026, 12.8637, 17.4579, 20.2144, 22.0521, 23.8897, 24.8086, 25.7274, 26.6462, 27.5651};
Y = {1, 1, , , , , 1, , 1, , 1};
```

I would like to get

```
{8.26953, 11.026, , , , , 23.8897, , 25.7274, , 27.5651}
```

then

```
{8.26953, 11.026, 23.8897, 25.7274, 27.5651}
```

Thanks for your help!
Teodoro Marinucci

I've found (found by someone else, for sure) two ways to do the second step:

```
DeleteCases[{8.26953, 11.026, , , , , 23.8897, , 25.7274, , 
  27.5651}, Null, {-1}]
{8.26953, 11.026, , , , , 23.8897, , 25.7274, , 27.5651} /. 
 Null -> Sequence[]
```

Now I need to do the first trasformation ...

Comment: Use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html), i.e., `Pick[X, Y, 1]`

Comment: Same solution, on the same time! Thanks

Comment: Your answer goes through unnecessary steps.

Comment: Please tell me how. Do you think that the MakeNormal is useless? I tried Pick[X, Y, 1] but it gives {}.

Comment: Since your answer uses different definitions than your question, I would guess that you are mixing your apples and oranges. Try `X = {8.26953, 11.026, 12.8637, 17.4579, 20.2144, 22.0521, 23.8897, 24.8086, 25.7274, 26.6462, 27.5651}; Y = {1, 1, , , , , 1, , 1, , 1}; Pick[X, Y, 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, why does `Table[If[y[[i]] == 1, x[[i]], Nothing], {i, Length@x}]` not work?

Comment: @NicholasG - Because `Null == 1` cannot be evaluated. Use `SameQ` rather than `Equal`, i.e., `Table[If[Y[[i]] === 1, X[[i]], Nothing], {i, Length@X}]`

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

```
X = {0.00937931, 0.0156307, , , , , 0.0643874, , 0.0706384, 0.0768894};
MakeNormal[x_] := If[x === Null, False, True]
Z = MakeNormal /@ X
Y = {8.26953, 11.026, 12.8637, 17.4579, 20.2144, 22.0521, 23.8897, 
   24.8086, 25.7274, 26.6462, 27.5651};
Pick[Y, Z]
DeleteCases[X, Null, {-1}]
```

Gives

```
{True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True}
{8.26953, 11.026, 23.8897, 25.7274, 27.5651}
{0.00937931, 0.0156307, 0.0643874, 0.0706384, 0.0768894}
```

Thanks!